# Quiting a job on German Niederlassungserlaubnis

Tags: germany, resident-permit

So I came to Germany back in 2016 and started working full time for an IT company. I got hold of the Blue card which gave me permission to work and I continued doing so for 3 years. Aftwards I got done with B1 language test and then applied for my *Niederlassungserlaubnis*. Got my *Niederlassungserlaubnis* just a few months ago (mid 2020). Everything good and fine.

The situation is that due to some circumstances in my current company, I would like to quit my job now because the mental stress of all the things happening are way too much to handle. There is also a very high chance that they force me to resign (not sure, though I would now want to resign now really and get it over with). The question is that would anything change in my residence status ? I do have some savings with me so I can easily support myself for 6 months or so and I also hope to find a new job during the notice period (3 months).

The only thing that is worrying me is that in case it takes longer than the notice period time to find a job, would the KVR or *Ausländerbehörde* or any other office needs to be informed ? Any thing that I have to do for my health insurance? I don't want to apply for *Arbeitslosgeld* since I have enough savings to support myself and I am in IT, so hopefully it won't also take a crazy amount of time to find another job. I just want to know if legally I am supposed to do something else or I just resign and start my search for another job?

Comment: You should report yourself as unemployed, since then you are insured. You should not resign, because that would make everything more complicated. You do not need to report to the Ausländerbehörde. Once you have received notice, you must report to the Job Center as unemployed to the given date. With that you will then have plenty of time to look for a new job.

Comment: So you mean as soon as I resign(without a new contract), I have to report to the job center immediately ?

Comment: At the latest before it comes effective. If you resign, the first 12 weeks you may not be eligible for coverage (including insurance). [Was tun bei drohender Arbeitslosigkeit? - Bundesagentur für Arbeit](https://www.arbeitsagentur.de/arbeitslosengeld/erste-schritte-arbeitslosigkeit)

Comment: Plese invest the time to inform yourself properly how this is done. Health insurance is **mandatory** in Germany. Not doing this correctly could effect your residence permit.

Comment: One more point is that it definitely makes sense to apply for ALG I, in such cases a former employee can receive 60-67% of his/her former salary for 1 year, which might be large amount of money. However, resigning from a current job without consulting a lawyer might be a bad idea, cause resigning might have the consequences that one will not be anymore eligible for ALG I.

Comment: Thank you very much for the replies ! Really helpful

Comment: I am exactly in your position now, except I had to resign due to current situation. I see in the agreement I am not able to claim unemployment benefit. My question is, how can I manage with TK insurance until I get my next job?